# I am experiencing random crash with uwp application on user device

Tags: uwp, crash

I am experiencing random crash with uwp application on user device. below is the crash dump

> Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS kernel32.dll
>
> version: 10.0.15063.608 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
>
> Machine Name: Debug session time: Wed Nov 15 05:55:26.000 2017 (UTC -
>   5:00)
>
> System Uptime: not available Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:25.000
>
> Kernel time: 0 days 0:00:01.000   User time: 0 days 0:00:05.000
>
> TRIAGER: Could not open triage file :
>   e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\oca.ini, error 2 TRIAGER: Could not
>   open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\winxp\triage.ini, error 2
>   TRIAGER: Could not open triage file :
>   e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\user.ini, error 2 Unable to load image
>   C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll, Win32 error 0n2
>
> *** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for KERNELBASE.dll
>
> *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for KERNELBASE.dll
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Exception Analysis                                   *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> Unable to load image C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll, Win32
>   error 0n2
>   *** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for twinapi.appcore.dll**
>    ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for twinapi.appcore.dll TRIAGER: Could not open triage file :
>   e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\guids.ini, error 2 Unable to load
>   image C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll, Win32 error 0n2
>    **WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for USER32.dll**
>    ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for USER32.dll TRIAGER: Could not open triage file :
>   e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2 GetUrlPageData2
>   (WinHttp) failed: 12029.
>    **The OS name list needs to be updated! Unknown Windows version: 10.0 ***
>
> FAULTING_IP:  twinapi_appcore+99e59 751c9e58 a802     add
>   r0,sp,#8
>
> EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
>   ExceptionAddress: 751c9e59 (twinapi_appcore+0x00099e59)
>   ExceptionCode: c000027b   ExceptionFlags: 00000001 NumberParameters: 2
>   Parameter[0]: 086491a0    Parameter[1]: 00000001
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  SimplifiedPOS.exe
>
> ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000027b -
>
> EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000027b -
>
> EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  086491a0
>
> EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000001
>
> NTGLOBALFLAG:  0
>
> APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0
>
> MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE No export dumpstack found
>
> MANAGED_BITNESS_MISMATCH:  Managed code needs matching platform of
>   sos.dll for proper analysis. Use 'Unk' debugger.
>
> LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00000000 to 76f95530
>
> FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff
>
> BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_APPLICATION_FAULT_No more specific
>   found_ZEROED_STACK
>
> PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT_No more specific found
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_No more specific found
>
> STACK_TEXT:   0443e188 00000000 : 00a17b90 00000018 6443ea28 6443da88
>   : KERNELBASE+0x155530
>
> STACK_COMMAND:  ~6s; .ecxr ; kb
>
> FOLLOWUP_IP:  twinapi_appcore+99e59 751c9e58 a802     add
>   r0,sp,#8
>
> SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0
>
> SYMBOL_NAME:  twinapi_appcore+99e59
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
>
> MODULE_NAME: twinapi_appcore
>
> IMAGE_NAME:  twinapi.appcore.dll
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: 
>   APPLICATION_FAULT_No_more_specific_found_c000027b_twinapi.appcore.dll!Unknown
>
> BUCKET_ID: 
>   ARM_APPLICATION_FAULT_APPLICATION_FAULT_No_more_specific_found_ZEROED_STACK_twinapi_appcore+99e59
>
> WATSON_STAGEONE_URL: 
>   http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/SimplifiedPOS_exe/1_0_0_0/58dc3ea5/twinapi_appcore_dll/10_0_15254_1/b4c800dc/c000027b/00099e59.htm?Retriage=1
>
> Followup: MachineOwner

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on your machine?

Comment: random crash is happening for my uwp application when web service  is called     ServiceReference2.Service1Client serviceclient = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
                    EndpointAddress eAddress = new EndpointAddress(ServiceURL);
                    serviceclient.Endpoint.Address = eAddress;serviceclient.UpdateCheecklockAsync(terminalid, checklock)